Bolzano-weierstrass theorem for sets, proof check
So I am studying Apostol's "Real analysis", and I'm in chapter 3 "basic point set topology" and on the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for sets.
I am wondering if my method is logically sound for this proof, namely in the way I create new subsets that contain infinite subsets of a set S, I assume all subsets contain a common point, this is where I want to be sure I am not messing up.
Here is the method although not fleshed out into a "proof"
Suppose $S$ is an infinite set in $R^n$ contained within some n-ball $B(0;a)$.
Then $S$ is contained within the $n$-dimensional interval ($n$-cell for short) $[-a,a]×[-a,a]×...×[-a,a]$.
We can split this n-cell into exactly $2^n$ new $n$-cells(for example a line can be split into 2 halves, a square can be split into 4 new squares, a cube into 8 smaller cubes), composed of the cross product of $n$ 1-dimensional intervals, of length $\frac{2a}{2} = a$.
At least one of these n-cells contains infinitely many points of $S$, call this $n$-cell $C_1$.
Repeat the process and split $C_1$ into $2^n$ new n-cells, composed of 1-dimensional intervals of length $a/2$. Choose the n-cell containing infinitely many points of $S$, call it $C_2$.
We may repeat the process to the mth n-cell, $C_m$ an n-cell, composed of n 1-dimensional intervals of length $a/2^{(m-1)}$.
Since $C_m$ is a subset of $C_{(m-1)}$ from the way we constructed them, and all $C_k$ contain infinitely many points of $S$ (implies they are non-empty), if we consider the infinite set of all n-cells constructed in this way $\{C_1,C_2,...C_m,...\}$, there must be some point $t$ that is an element of all n-cells $C_k$And then we proceed to show t is an accumulation point, since for any n-ball $B(t;r)$, we simply choose m sufficiently large s.t. $C_m$ is contained within $B(t;r)$, and since $C_m$ contains an infinite subset of S, we are done and t is an accumulation point of S.
(I know the last part would have to be described better, but Im interested in if I can assert that t exists, since all n-cells $C_k$ are subsets of one another, they must contain a common member t?)
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Many thanks

Please use MathJax to format the mathematics in your question.

The step that the intersection of these nested stes is nonempty is indeed the crucial step.

The correct name is Bolzano, not Bolanzo

@HagenvonEitzen is it provable or circular reasoning? Cantor intersection theorem looks suspiciously similar to my understanding of the proof for BWT, but BWT is used to prove cantor intersection theorem, not sure how I can show that all sets share an element, they are all non empty, they are all nested, they all contain infinitely many points of $S$ by definition, is it possible to use contradiction to show for example: If $\bigcap_{k\in N} C_k = \emptyset$ , then one of the sets contains no elements of $S$ which is a contradiction?

To justify that $\cap C_k\ne\varnothing$: wlog $n=1$, and then $C_k=[a_k,b_k]$ where $(a_k)$ is non-decreasing, $(b_k)$ non-increasing, and $b_k-a_k\to0$...

@AnneBauval so you are using the nested interval theorem?

Indeed (which is a much more elementary special case of Cantor intersection theorem), or if you prefer: the monotone convergence theorem. I can edit these comments as an answer if you want, but I would be happier to upvote a self-answer from you instead.

@AnneBauval I have an answer on paper, will write it up shortly!

Regarding the existence of a point in the intersection of all n-cells.
We know the n-cells are constructed of n 1-dimensional closed intervals.
Say $C_k=[a_{k,1},b_{k,1}]\times...\times[a_{k,n},b_{k,n}]$.
Let indexing set $I=\{i\in \mathbb{Z} : 1\leq i \leq n\}$.
Then from the property $C_{k}\supseteq C_{k+1}$, we have $[a_{k,i},b_{k,i}]\supseteq [a_{k+1,i},b_{k+1,i}]$ for all $i\in I$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Now consider the ith 1-dimensional interval in the n-cells.
Clearly $[a_{1,i},b_{1,i}]\supseteq[a_{2,i},b_{2,i}]\supseteq...\supseteq [a_{k,i},b_{k,i}]\supseteq ...$, all the intervals are nested.
Consider the sets of left endpoints $A_i=\{a_{k,i};k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and right endpoints $B_i=\{b_{k,i};k\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
Since the intervals are nested, every $b_{i,k}\in B_i$ can serve as an upper bound for $A_i$, then $A_i$ is bounded above, so Sup$A_i$ exists, say $t_i$. Then $a_{k,i}\leq t_i$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Now, since $t_i$ is the supremum of $A_i$, it is less than or equal to all other upper bounds, but every $b_{k,i}\in B_i$ is an upper bound of $A_i$, therefore $a_{k,i}\leq t_i \leq b_{k,i}$.
Which is to say $t_i \in [a_{k,i},b_{k,i}]$, for any $i\in I$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Therefore $t_i \in\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[a_{k,i},b_{k,i}]\neq \emptyset$. Which tells us further that:
We have a point $t=(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)\in \bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}[a_{k,1},b_{k,1}]\times [a_{k,2},b_{k,2}]\times ... \times [a_{k,n},b_{k,n}]=\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb{N}}C_k$.
Which is proof that indeed a point $t$ exists, and is a member of every n-cell.
